# Alternative to installing Docker locally (Win 10 Home) for AWS serverless development

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am setting up a local environment for developing serverless lambda functions that I want to deploy to my aws account. I am using this user guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/key-tasks.html#key-tasks-install

I have managed to get up to step 12.b (Docker (Docker must always be running whenever you develop, test, analyze, or deploy serverless applications or functions)) and hit a brick wall because my OS is Win 10 Home Edition.

I researched posts re installing Docker on this OS and it seems very involved, i.e. needs VirtualBox etc. I read about it here: https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/01/docker-on-windows10-home-scratch.html

Before going further down the rabbit hole, I wanted to ask whether anyone has had experience setting up their dev environment with this aws user guide, with an alternative to installing Docker locally. I.e. is it possible to use a 'managed' or 'remote' docker service for this?

Hope this all makes sense- I appreciate any support!

Andy

Comment: The easiest method is going to be purchasing a Windows 10 Pro upgrade license for your workstation. Every developer's workstation needs to be able to run Docker these days.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your reply. This is very helpful to know. I’ve been out of the IT world for a while and just starting to get back into it again. I will explore the upgrade option. Regards. Andy.